# is there any possible way to get an actual wave length of a raw .wav file using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get an actual wave length of a raw .wav file using c# but I am struggling to find the best solution.

Is there any algorithm that I can use to do this using c#?

please help me..

Comment: What do you mean by `wave length` ? Can you load a WAV? Yes. Can you apply filters? Yes, using libraries like NAudio or CScore, or wrappers over FFMPEG.  Wavelength is the inverse of the frequency though, and audio files definitely contain more than one frequency.

Comment: Yes you can.  Not sure exactly what you mean but I'm assuming you want to draw a waveform from a wav file and display it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629277/analyzing-wav-and-drawing-a-graph

Comment: Wavelength also depends on the medium the wave is travelling through

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos  Thank you so much, I just used NAudio and everything seems to be okay...